# Apk File Deleted. Need to regenerate

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I accidently deleted my project apk file from my Eclipse Project directory and now I cannot run my project. Any suggestions on how I can generate the apk file?

Comment: don't you have the code? just export another apk !!

Comment: Sorry. But how would deleting an APK prevent your project from running?

Comment: @StinePike: When I try to export unsigned or signed application package, it tells me that Android Library Projects cannot be exported. When I try to run my project, it says could not find the .apk

Comment: Try cleaning your project

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project in the navigator, go to `Properties -> Android` and uncheck `Is Library`.

You seem to have turned your project into a library project, which well prevent apks from being made, and only give you JARs.